# Is it good to call Thread.Sleep during polling Google Big Query results in ASP.NET? Alternatives?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, google-bigquery

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 which gets data from Google Big Query. Due to the way Google Big Query is designed, I need to poll for results if job is not finished. Here is my code,

```
       var qr = new QueryRequest
        {
            Query = string.Format(myQuery, param1, param2)
        };// all params are mine
        var jobs = _bigqueryService.Jobs;
        var response = await jobs.Query(qr, _settings.GoogleCloudServiceProjectId).ExecuteAsync();
        var jobId = response.JobReference.JobId;
        var isCompleted = response.JobComplete == true;
        IList<TableRow> rows = response.Rows;
        while (!isCompleted)
        {
            var r = await jobs.GetQueryResults(_settings.GoogleCloudServiceProjectId, jobId).ExecuteAsync();
            isCompleted = r.JobComplete == true;
            if (!isCompleted)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            else
            {
                rows = r.Rows;
            }
        }
```

Looking at this code can someone tell me whether its good to call Thread.Sleep inside this context or I should continuously burn CPU cycles.

Comment: No. Use `Task.Delay()` so you don't kill scalability by tying up threads.

Comment: @Crowcoder can you please answer this by updating my code.

Comment: @Crowcoder you mean `await Task.Delay(100);`

Comment: yes, await. It will take some refactoring. I would write an answer if I had time right now, but the Google and Stephen Cleary will help you. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't do this on the server side as one have to be careful which waiting calls to use to avoid high resource consumption under load.

Your users also don't get any feedback from the page. You can improve this situation by displaying a spinning wheel, but it might be better to show actual progress to the users.

A better way of doing this will be AJAX calls to your web site. The call may return something like status, time elapsed and percentage complete (have a look at the BigTable's API). In this case you don't need to do any `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Delay` kung fu.

**Edit:**
Oh, you already using AJAX! Just tear off any `Thread.Sleep` and return result immediately to users. In browser, when AJAX call is completed update UI with information from the AJAX call. Job done.

Comment: I am doing this on Ajax BTW.

Comment: agreed, much better client side